# Submit form fields from both web page and included iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a web page from my web site with a form and some fields inside it. In this page I also have a iframe pointing to another page in my web site. This page opens inside the iframe as a form with many fields also.

The main page as a submit button. When I click the submit button the page is submitted to the same web page at server side. And then I can get the fields values. However, I dont understand what is going on with the iframe fields. At server side the page load event of the page where the iframe is pointing is executed, but I cant get any of the iframe fields. So, it seems the iframe form is not being submitted.

Shouldnt the iframe be submitted also?

thank you,

fwu

Comment: Post your code, or better yet, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You're expecting fields on another page to be submitted with your form? That's a tall order, I think. Or is it two separate forms?

Answer (score 1):

The form submit doesn't submit the iframe contents. 
Instead of adding the page as a iframe, you should include the contents of that file as part of your page. Since both the pages are hosted on your server, this might be easier.

Comment: Right. It's fairly easy to include a page or part of a page using ajax.

Comment: Im loading the second page in an iform because this page has javascript and styles. I tried to make an innerhtml to an html object content but the css and javascript stop working. So, how can I add all the page stuff inside an existent page? thank you